# How do I make my Python 3 code more compact

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm obviously quite new to python. So the code I wrote for my assignment gives me the right output, however, it just hurts your eyes to look at. So I was wondering if there is a way to make the code more compact?

Here's my code:

```
import sys

period_count = 0
excl_count = 0
quest_count = 0
colon_count = 0
dquote_count = 0
comma_count = 0
scolon_count = 0
slash_count = 0
bslash_count = 0
lparen_count = 0
rparen_count = 0
quote_count = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    for char in line:
        if char == ".":
            period_count = period_count + 1
        if char == "!":
            excl_count = excl_count +1
        if char == "?":
            quest_count = quest_count +1
        if char == ":":
            colon_count = colon_count +1
        if char == "\"":
            dquote_count = dquote_count +1
        if char == ",":
            comma_count = comma_count +1
        if char == ";":
            scolon_count = scolon_count +1
        if char == "/":
            slash_count = slash_count +1
        if char == "\\":
            bslash_count = bslash_count +1
        if char == "(":
            lparen_count = lparen_count +1
        if char == "(":
            rparen_count = rparen_count +1  
        if char == "'":
            quote_count = quote_count +1    

print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>4} {2:>5} {0:>4}".format("|", "mark", "number"))
print("{0} {1} {0} {2} {0}".format("|", "_______", "_________"))                

print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", ".", period_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "!", excl_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "?", quest_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", ":", colon_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "\"", dquote_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", ",", comma_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", ";", scolon_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "/", slash_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "\\", bslash_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "(", lparen_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", ")", rparen_count))
print("{0} {1:>3} {0:>5} {2:>5} {0:>5}".format("|", "'", quote_count))
```

And the assignment was to count each punctuation mark individually and print that mark plus the results in a table.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com is the right site for code reviews.

Answer (score 3):

You can hash on strings, and credit to tobias_k for the comprehension:

```
dictionary = {c: 0 for c in ".!?:\",;/\\()'"}

for line in sys.stdin:
   for char in line:
      if char in dictionary:
          dictionary[char] += 1

for char, counter in dictionary.items():
    print(...) # formatted string goes here
```

### Edit

Per conversation with Chris_Rands in the comments, if the assignment was to simply count all punctuation marks then I recommend changing the above slightly:

```
import string
dictionary = {c: 0 for c in string.punctuation}
```

Rest follows as above. `string.punctuation` is `'!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~'` on my machine (the set is locale-based according to the docs).

### Final Update

Credit to Muposat for reminding me of defaultdict: no need to initialize the keys and counters when `0` is the default value for the `int` constructor:

```
import sys
import string

dictionary = defaultdict(int)
for line in sys.stdin:
    for char in line:
        if char in string.punctuation:
            dictionary[char] += 1


for char, counter in dictionary.items():
    print(...) # formatted string goes here
```

Comment: Shorter: `dictionary = {c: 0 for c in ".!?:\",;/\\()'"}`

Comment: I suggest using `string.punctuation`

Comment: @Chris_Rands is that strictly equivalent to the original character set? The OP's seems to be missing some punctuation marks.

Comment: Not it's not identical, but likely what they want as they say " the assignment was to count each punctuation mark"

Comment: `dictionary = defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 0):

This shorter version will count *all* character frequencies, using the builtin class `collections.Counter`, and print the desired ones (including original table formatting):

```
import sys, collections
freqs = collections.Counter(char for line in sys.stdin.readlines() for char in line)
print("|  mark | count |")
print("|_______|_______|")
for char in ".!?:\",;/\\()'":
  print("| {:>5} | {:>5} |".format(char, freqs.get(char, 0)))
```

Or the same idea in one line, just for fun:

```
(lambda freqs=__import__('collections').Counter(char for line in __import__('sys').stdin.readlines() for char in line):print("|  mark | count |\n|_______|_______|\n"+"".join("| {:>5} | {:>5} |\n".format(char, freqs.get(char, 0)) for char in ".!?:\",;/\\()'")))()
```